# Request a resource with percent sign in path

Tags: apache, url, character-encoding, urlencode

I need to request a file `www.myserver.de/file%.pdf` .
The file exists and requesting the renamed copy `www.myserver.de/file.pdf` works.

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

% is the character for URL escape sequences. Try using %25 which decodes to a single % sign.

Answer (score 1):

% has a special meaning in URLs, so you need to escape it in order to refer to files with %s in their names.

Try `www.myserver.de/file%25.pdf` instead.